# fuse: error creating thread: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: c, fuse

After writing **getattr** and **readdir** functions for simplest fuse filesystem, i get ***fuse: error creating thread: Resource temporarily unavailable.***. I would like to know where in my code i made mistake

I already search for this, but couldnt find anything that satisfies me. It seems to me that it exceeded thread limit, but i dont know how to fix it. I compiled it with

```
$ gcc passthrough.c -o passthrough `pkg-config fuse --cflags --libs`
passthrough.c:65:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  .getattr = e_getattr,
  ^
passthrough.c:65:2: warning: (near initialization for 'oper.getattr') [enabled by default]
```

Here is the source code of program

```
#define FUSE_USE_VERSION 26

#include <fuse.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <limits.h>

char rootdir[100];

void get_fullpath(char fpath[PATH_MAX], const char *path){
    strcpy(fpath,rootdir);
    strncat(fpath,path,PATH_MAX);
    printf("[fullpath] file: %s\n",fpath);
}

int e_getattr(const char *path, struct stat *stbuf, struct fuse_file_info *fi){
    (void)fi;
    int res;

    char fpath[PATH_MAX];
    get_fullpath(fpath,path);

    printf("[getattr] file: %s\n",fpath);

    res = lstat(fpath,stbuf);
    if (res == -1)
        return -errno;
    return 0;
}

int e_readdir(const char *path, void *buf, fuse_fill_dir_t filler, off_t offset, struct fuse_file_info *fi){
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *de;

    (void)offset;
    (void)fi;

    char fpath[PATH_MAX];
    get_fullpath(fpath,path);
    printf("[readdir] file: %s\n",fpath);

    dp = opendir(fpath);
    if (dp == NULL)
        return -errno;

    while ((de = readdir(dp)) != NULL){
        struct stat st;
        memset(&st,0,sizeof(st));
        st.st_ino = de->d_ino;
        st.st_mode = de->d_type << 12;
        if (filler(buf,de->d_name,&st,0))
            break;
    }
    closedir(dp);
    return 0;
}

struct fuse_operations oper = {
    .getattr = e_getattr,
    .readdir = e_readdir,
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    umask(0);
    realpath(argv[2],rootdir);
    printf("Real path is %s\n",rootdir);
    return fuse_main(argc,argv,&oper,NULL);
}
```

And here is the output i'm getting

```
[fullpath] file: /home/echo/passthrough/test/
[getattr] file: /home/echo/passthrough/test/
[fullpath] file: /home/echo/passthrough/test/
[getattr] file: /home/echo/passthrough/test/
[fullpath] file: /home/echo/passthrough/test/
[getattr] file: /home/echo/passthrough/test/
[fullpath] file: /home/echo/passthrough/test/
[getattr] file: /home/echo/passthrough/test/
[fullpath] file: /home/echo/passthrough/test/
[getattr] file: /home/echo/passthrough/test/
[fullpath] file: /home/echo/passthrough/test/
[getattr] file: /home/echo/passthrough/test/
...
...
...
[fullpath] file: /home/echo/passthrough/test/
[getattr] file: /home/echo/passthrough/test/
fuse: error creating thread: Resource temporarily unavailable
[fullpath] file: /home/echo/passthrough/test/
[getattr] file: /home/echo/passthrough/test/
```

Comment: I wonder why `passthrough.c:65:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  .getattr = e_getattr,` happens... seems to match `int(*  getattr )(const char *, struct stat *, struct fuse_file_info *fi)` though...

Comment: That is also one of the things that is confusing me, i followed passthrough.c from libfuse github

Comment: suggest reading: [how to use fuse](https://github.com/fntlnz/fuse-example/blob/master/fuse-example.c)

Comment: OT: regarding: `realpath(argv[2],rootdir);`  Never access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure that the expected command line parameters were actually entered.  When they were not entered by the user, then output to `stderr`, a USAGE message similar to: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <descriptiion of each parameter>\n", argv[0] ); followed by: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  Also, what is expected for `argv[1]`?  It is never used in the posted code

Comment: regarding: `strncat(fpath,path,PATH_MAX);`   Must not use: `PATH_MAX` because part of the array `fpath` is already containing the data from `path`.   so that third parameter should be similar to: `PATH_MAX - (strlen( path ) +1)`

Comment: Please provide the actual link to your source information in `gitlib`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is in the function: `e_getattr()`  It should be written as:

```
static int e_getattr(const char *path, struct stat *stbuf )
{
    int res;

    char fpath[PATH_MAX];
    get_fullpath(fpath,path);

    printf("[getattr] file: %s\n",fpath);

    res = lstat(fpath,stbuf);
    if (res == -1)
        return -ENONET;
    return 0;
}
```

Notice the added modifier `static`

Notice the removal of the third function parameter

Notice the modification to the return (on error) to `-ENONET`

Also the list of included header files is missing the statement;

```
#include <stdlib.h> // exposes function: `realpath()`
```

the function: `e_getattr()` also needs the `static modifier

Comment: it solved the warnings during compilation, however output of running is still the same like in the answer

Comment: do you mean: "like in the question"?

Comment: the question was about the compiler warnings and about not being able to start another thread.  This answer is about the compiler warnings as they need to be corrected first